# Looping through active directory nested security groups in SharePoint

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ssom

Is there a way to loop through the nested security groups in active directory, with or without using LDAP in SharePoint??

I have tried SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup but Im not geting nested groups in AD.

Comment: i was talking about doing it in sharepoint !!

Answer (score 0):

Without LDAP, am not sure that it would be possible or not. As AD sync to Userprofile o what you need, you can get from user profile instead on AD in SharePoint.